# Tortoise SVN bugtrack URL hyperlink to BUGID does not work after the commit, when viewed under SVN showlog

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, redmine

I am trying to connect the SVN commit msgs to the Task ID under Redmine. Below is the properties set :

[image]

While entering the commit message the #%BUGID% connects to the mentioned url and open the webpage when clicked. But, after the commit when tried to access from the log message, it still appears as hyperlink (blue and the mouse pointer changes when went over) but doesnot open the webpage.

Tried to copy the link and could see that it is the mentioned URL without the BUGID being replaced. (`http://192.168.25.36/redmine/issues/%BUGID%`)

Comment: I think that you need to use plugin https://github.com/jlestein/turtlemine

Comment: I do am using it. That's when #ID in commit message links to the Ticket and opens up the webpage when clicked. The same thing doesnot work after commit when looked from logs